# PAD symbol "r<3>" has an undefined IOSTANDARD - Verilog

Tags: verilog, xilinx-ise

I was writing Booth Multiplier code in ***Verilog***.
I'm getting the following errors.

```
PAD symbol "r<3>" has an undefined IOSTANDARD
PAD symbol "r<3>" is not constrained (LOC) to a specific location.
```

I Don't want to test it in FPGA. Just need to stimulate in Xilinx ISE. So I did **not** write the `ucf file`.

> Even though I'm getting this error, my stimulation is working perfectly.

1. Is `ucf file` always necessary?
2. How will I fix this?

The error doesn't let me generate the `programming file`.
Here is my code. *(r used statements are commented)*

```
module boothMulti( r, q, product 
    );
    input [3:0] r, q;           // Declaration of r[r shows error.]
    output reg [7:0] product;
    reg [8:0] a, b, p;
    reg [5:0] c;
    integer i;

    always@(q or r) begin       // r used here
        a[0]=0;
        b[0]=0;
        p[0]=0;

//setting up c
        c[0]=0;
        c[4:1]=r;               // r used here

//setting up a
        a[4:1]=q[3:0];
        a[8:5]=4'b0000;
        if(q[3]==0) begin a[8:5]=4'b0000; end
        else begin a[8:5]=4'b1111; end

//setting up b
        b[4:1]=((~q)+4'b0001);
        if(b[4]==0) begin b[8:5]=4'b0000; end
        else begin b[8:5]=4'b1111; end

//setting up p
        p[8:1]=8'b00000000;

    for( i=1; i<5; i=i+1) begin         
        case({c[i],c[i-1]})
            2'b0_0:begin
                    a=a<<<1; b=b<<<1;
                    end
            2'b0_1:begin
                    p=p+a;
                    a=a<<<1; b=b<<<1;
                    end
            2'b1_0:begin
                    p=p+b;
                    a=a<<<1; b=b<<<1;
                    end
            2'b1_1:begin
                    a=a<<<1; b=b<<<1;
                    end
            endcase
        end                 //end for loop
        product[7:0]=p[8:1];
    end                     //end always@
endmodule
```

Comment: That was post place & route simulation ? Of what I remember for this simulation ucf file is auto generated. Sorry for My English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just simulated this design successfully: it compiled and ran for a bit, but, bearing in mind you did not post a testbench, everything was `x`. I also managed to generate a programming file.

How about

- quitting from ISE,
- restarting,
- closing the project and
- creating a completely new project?

There may be something lurking in your existing project that is causing this.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But still I didn't understand the problem.
What I did is precisely what you said.
I think problem identification is also necessary.

Comment: I think it would be quite hard to find the specific problem. In my experience of using FPGA tools from any vendor, sometimes those tools get into some funny state and the quickest and easiest way to get out of that state is to delete the project and start again.